# How to use Biml to generate conditional split transform

Tags: ssis, biml

When I did archive job in ssis, I want to compare PK between source and destination, but there are some tables with different PK names, and some of them have composite primary keys. So I tried to use foreach function to get list of columns, but I got stuck on conditional split, how could I set Expression?

Example below: i don't know what should I put into expression of Conditional split. I only want 2 conditions, one is 'Add new' (Check if any of DST_Columns is null) and the other is  'Already Exists' (Check if all DST_Columns == SRC_Column)

```
<MergeJoin Name="MRGJ - <#=tbl.Name#> RowId" JoinType = 'FullOuterJoin'>
    <LeftInputPath OutputPathName="OLESRC - Archive_PKList_<#=tbl.Name#>.Output">
        <Columns>
        <#
        var indexSortKey = 1;
            foreach(var column in tbl.Columns.Where(c => c.IsUsedInPrimaryKey)) {
            #>
                <Column SourceColumn="<#=column.Name#>" SortKeyPosition="<#=indexSortKey.ToString()#>" TargetColumn="DST_<#=column.Name#>" />              
            <#
                indexSortKey++;  
            } #>
        </Columns>
    </LeftInputPath>
    <RightInputPath OutputPathName="OLESRC - Source <#=tbl.Name#>.Output">
        <Columns>
                <#
        indexSortKey = 1;
            foreach(var column in tbl.Columns.Where(c => c.IsUsedInPrimaryKey)) {
            #>
                <Column SourceColumn="<#=column.Name#>" SortKeyPosition="<#=indexSortKey.ToString()#>" TargetColumn="SRC_<#=column.Name#>" />              
            <#
                indexSortKey++;  
            } #>
        </Columns>
    </RightInputPath>
        <JoinKeys>
            <#foreach(var column in tbl.Columns.Where(c => c.IsUsedInPrimaryKey)) { #>
                <JoinKey LeftColumn="DST_<#=column.Name#>" RightColumn="SRC_<#=column.Name#>"></JoinKey>
            <# } #>
        </JoinKeys>
    </MergeJoin>
    <ConditionalSplit Name="Conditional_Split">
    <OutputPaths>
        <OutputPath Name="New_Records" IsErrorOutput="false">
            <Expression>
                    <#foreach(var column in tbl.Columns.Where(c => c.IsUsedInPrimaryKey)) { #>
                        ISNULL (DST_<#=column.Name#>) .... I don''t know
            </Expression>
        </OutputPath>
        <OutputPath Name="Already_Exists" IsErrorOutput="false">
            <Expression> <#foreach(var column in tbl.Columns.Where(c => c.IsUsedInPrimaryKey)) { #>
                SRC_<#=column.Name#> == DST_<#=column.Name#> --- not sure either
                <# } #>
            </Expression>
        </OutputPath>
    </OutputPaths>
    </ConditionalSplit>
```

I searched online but Biml document is limited. And I'm not very familiar with c# either, so if you know some good source please also let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a ConditionalSplit problem per se, you have a logic problem. You have a merge join, in `full outer join` mode and the result of this is that you'll have columns preface with SRC and DST. Based on whether the column is `IsUsedInPrimaryKey` then you either use a join key or not.

Coming out of this MergeJoin, either the SRC has a match in the DST or it doesn't (as shown by SRC_ColumnName(s) being NULL). You can probably simplify this by checking just the first column that is `IsUsedInPrimaryKey` unless you have a nullable key in which this goes into a consulting project ;)

If there's a match, only then do we want to compare each SRC column to the mate in the DST column. And realistically, we can exclude the IsUsedInPrimaryKey as we know they will match because that's how we got here.

As I often encourage people when working with SSIS, don't do too much in a place where it's hard to debug. In this case, I would add 2 Derived Columns between the MergeJoin and your ConditionalSplit because it's going to be much, much easier to debug the intended expressions.

### DER IsNew

We're going to add a column into the data flow called IsNew as this will identify whether the SRC row has a match in the DST.

The goal here is to build a string that is simply

`ISNULL(DST_PrimaryKeyCol1)`

```
<#
    // This is all approximate code, actual syntax and values may vary
    string first_keyColumn = tbl.Columns.Where(c => c.IsUsedInPrimaryKey)).FirstOrDefault(); 
    string der_IsNew = "ISNULL(DST_{0})".format(first_keyColumn);
#>
        <DerivedColumns Name="DER IsNew">
            <Columns>
                <Column DataType="Boolean" Name="IsNew"><#=der_IsNew#></Column>
            </Columns>
        </DerivedColumns>
```

### DER IsChanged

This is going to be the harder one, simply because you may run into a length limitation of the SSIS Expression language of 8000 characters (citation needed).

The goal of this step is to build out a string that uses the following pattern

```
(SRC_Column0 != DST_Column0) || (SRC_ColumnN != DST_ColumnN)
```

Where the double pipes `||` are logical ORs because we want this new column to be True when any of the columns do not match.

```
<#
    string testTemplate = "(SRC_{0} != DST{0})";
    // This is all approximate code, actual syntax and values may vary
    List<string> non_keyColumns = tbl.Columns.Where(c => !c.IsUsedInPrimaryKey)).Select(c => testTemplate.Format(c.Name)).ToList<string>(); 
    // At this point, we have a list of just the column names in test format
    // Use the .Join operator to concat/aggregate the rows into one big one
    string der_IsChanged = "||".join(non_keyColumns);
#>

        <DerivedColumns Name="DER IsChanged">
            <Columns>
                <Column DataType="Boolean" Name="IsChanged"><#=der_IsChanged#></Column>
            </Columns>
        </DerivedColumns>
```

### Conditional Split

So now, your conditional split is simplified. You'll have two custom outputs

```
<ConditionalSplit Name="Conditional_Split">
    <OutputPaths>
        <OutputPath Name="New_Records" IsErrorOutput="false">
            <Expression>IsNew</Expression>
        </OutputPath>
        <OutputPath Name="Already_Exists" IsErrorOutput="false">
            <Expression>IsChanged</Expression>
        </OutputPath>
    </OutputPaths>
</ConditionalSplit>
```

Documentation:

- [BimlScript.com](https://BimlScript.com)
- https://docs.varigence.com/biml-reference/api-reference/Varigence.Languages.Biml.Table.AstTableNode (that's a link in to the class level documentation for Biml although I couldn't find ConditionalSplit quickly)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I just changed a very few things and it works for me! I just know you are the author of The Biml Book, and I bought it last week, but i'm not good at c# either, should I learn c# first, and then back to Biml?

Comment: The good thing about Biml, as I see it, is that you can go as deep or as light into the object model (and therefore C#). I thought Scott did an excellent job with the walk through on the BImlScript site. Specifically, his [C# Primer](https://bimlscript.com/walkthrough/Details/3117) should give you a solid platform to start with. The other "good thing" to learn would be LINQ, which you seem to have a bit of already but mastery is not required - you'll just write more verbose code.